# How to call Object items in array with Mongo/Meteor?

Tags: meteor

In my Mongo database, I have products and each of these products have images.

[image]

I would like to know how I can call each image in put them in a Meteor template. I know things like `{{#each}}{{/each}}` exist, but I don't know how to capture the `images` object.

With this code...

```
  Template.products.helpers({
    product: function () {
      return ProductList.find();
    }
  });
```

I am able to call the first image like:

```
<img src="{{images.[0]}}" alt="{{title}}"/>
```

I could hardcode the rest of the images, but I would like to do this dynamically. Any tips?

EDIT: Here is the expected HTML output (the extra classes on `.content__product` are added dynamically via a separate function):

```
<section class="content__products">
  <figure class="content__product selected">
    <img src="/images/product/tt-shirt-01.jpg" alt="Time Travel Tee">
  </figure>

  <figure class="content__product move-down">
    <img src="/images/product/tt-shirt-02.jpg" alt="Time Travel Tee">
  </figure>

  <figure class="content__product">
    <img src="/images/product/tt-shirt-03.jpg" alt="Time Travel Tee">
  </figure>
</section>
```

Comment: So each <figure> is a different product? and then you only want one product image per <figure>?

Comment: On the homepage, each figure is a different product. That new code is the individual product page. I wanted all of the images for that product to show up, so people could see different looks/variations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so the code posted here helped me out, but didn't solve my issue out of the box. Here is how I changed my code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.products.helpers({
    product: function () {
      return ProductList.find();
    }
  });

  Template.product.helpers({
    imgList: function () {
      var imgs = [];

      _.each(this.images, function (img) {
        imgs.push({imgPath: img});
      });

      return imgs;
    }
  });

}
```

And, my template:

```
<template name="product">
  <section class="content__products">
    {{#each imgList}}
      <figure class="content__product">
        <img src="/{{imgPath}}" alt="{{../title}}"/>
      </figure>
    {{/each}}
  </section>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

`each` works for both cursors and arrays, so you can do something like this:

```html
{{#each products}}
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>
  {{#each images}}
    <img src={{this}} alt={{../title}}>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Recommended reading: [A Guide to Meteor Templates & Data Contexts](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/)

Comment: I'm AFK at the moment, so I can't try this out yet, but how will `{{src}}` know how to grab the images?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo - try the new version.

Answer (score 0):

{{#each}} only accepted array or cursor of Mongo collection. So you have to change your object to array and make another template.
This is sample code for you.

```js
if(Meteor.isClient){
  Template.product.helpers({
    list : function(){
      return Products.find({});
    }
  });
  
  Template.productImg.helpers({
    imgList: function(){
      var imgs = [];
      _.each(this.images, function(img){
        imgs.push({imgPath: img});
      });
      return imgs;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<template name="product">
  {{#each list}}
    {{> productImg}}
  {{/each}}
</template>


<template name="productImg">
  {{#each imgList}}
    <img src="{{imgPath}}" alt="{{../title}}"/>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: I'm AFK at the moment, but your code looks like it's what I'm looking for! I'll test in a couple of hours.

Comment: This is an over complicated solution. You don't have to separate the object like this, please refer to David Wheldon's correct solution.

Comment: Actually @IanJones, his code helped me more. I'm about to post my answer.

Comment: @NetOperatorWibby there was a typo in David Wheldon's answer, it now works properly. It's also the best practice method and far simpler.

Comment: @IanJones Well for some reason, it didn't work for me. Also, did you downvote me? EDIT: Here's video of my layout (coded), so you can see what I was aiming to do, dynamically > https://instagram.com/p/0gh_PhvOw7

Comment: @NetOperatorWibby Maybe I'm mis-interpreting your question. If you amend your original question to include an HTML only example of the intended output then this will help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

For an individual product page I would do it like this:

```
Template.products.helpers({
    'products': function() {
        return ProductList.find();
    }
});
```

**Multiple images** per product:

```
<section class="content__products">
    {{#each products}}
        <figure class="content__product">
            {{#each images}}
                <img src="{{this}}" alt="{{../title}}">
            {{/each}}
        </figure>
    {{/each}}
</section>
```

**Single image** per product:

```
<section class="content__products">
    {{#each products}}
        <figure class="content__product">
            <img src="{{images.[0]}}" alt="{{../title}}">
        </figure>
    {{/each}}
</section>
```

Comment: I'm pretty tired, so I may have mis-interpreted everything... but this is what I think you need in the simplest way possible.

Comment: I have a layout called "products", so I think that may be the reason why these other answers aren't working. I'll try again in the morning. I have it working now, but if I can make the code simpler, that's definitely something to work towards.